# How can I prevent html tags from being red underlined inside of .ejs files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ejs

If I start an .ejs file with a tag like h1, it is underlined in red, like VSCode expects me to add the whole typical html boilerplate. However, I have seen many videos where the host doesn't get this underlining.

I have tried extensions, I have modified the settings.json with "*.ejs": "html", but nothing works.

Do you know how I can get rid of it without having to add DOCTYPE, , etc.?

Comment: Maybe it is something related to a lint included in your project on VSC? ESLint/JSLint?

Comment: Any idea which one exactly could be causing this? I don't know much about Lints :/

Comment: lints are meant to correct your code comparing to known standards and syntax issues. I am not sure what lint do you have over there. If you are hovering the underlined tag, can you share the warning that you see?

Comment: Sure. This is the whole error message: "<h1>
The h1 element represents a section heading.

MDN Reference

Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected “<!DOCTYPE html>”.W3C Validator
Element “head” is missing a required instance of child element “title”.W3C Validator
Consider adding a “lang” attribute to the “html” start tag to declare the language of this document.W3C Validator
Peek Problem (Alt+F8)
No quick fixes available"

Comment: umm.. so you might have W3C Validator installed.. you can try and disable it on "extensions" in Visual Studio Code... However, I would recommend following those notes in order to write valid document. So consider keep using that validator and fix the things he says you should fix :)

Comment: You were right, disabling W3C Validator solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll write that as an answer so others can get that help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after figuring out that this problem caused by a lint or other validator (in this case W3C Validator) installed as an extension in Visual Studio Code, you can disable its warnings by going to extensions and disable the validator.

However, those tools are here for a reason :) and they help us write better code that fits to known standards and syntax issues, so disabling them is less recommended. (Although it can become bit annoying while using external third-party libs which can be can some warnings by that validator too - for that, some lints offers ignoring logic which let you ignore some of the files or lines in the code).

Good Luck, Happy coding!